# Django de-structuring of URLs

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am learning the Django Web Framework but just could not work my head around this logic.
Let's say we have a Django App that has a very big urls.py where all the patterns are stored here. How would one go about splitting this into a urls folder, wherein it contains multiple 'urls.py' files? And not only that, to have a nested directory within the urls folder as well.

Example project structure of what I am thinking of:

```
>main_base
 >__init__.py
 >asgi.py
 >settings.py
 >wsgi.py
 >urls.py
>secondary_app
 >admin.py
 >apps.py
 >models.py
 >__init__.py
 >views
  >home.py
  >idea.py
  >project.py
  >business_partners
   >customers.py
   >vendors.py
 >urls
  >__init__.py
  >home.py
  >idea.py
  >project.py
  >business_partners
   >__init__.py
   >customers.py
   >vendors.py
```

in main_base/urls,
I would have the following:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('secondary_app.urls')),
]
```

in secondary_app/urls/**init**.py,
I would expect to do the following:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('secondary_app.urls.home')),
    path('', include('secondary_app.urls.idea')),
    path('', include('secondary_app.urls.project')),
    path('', include('secondary_app.urls.business_partners')),
]
```

And lastly in secondary_app/urls/business_partners/**init**.py,
I would do the following:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('secondary_app.urls.business_partners.customers')),
    path('', include('secondary_app.urls.business_partners.vendors')),
]
```

I have tested it and it works all the way up till the secondary_app/urls directory level.
But once I go one more level down, it throws a reverse match not found error.
Example error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'bp-customers' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['bp/customers']
```

Any help is really really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your views in separate files do this (assuming CBV):

main_base/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('secondary_app.urls')),
]
```

secondary_app/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views.home import HomeViewName
from .views.idea import IdeaViewName

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeViewName.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('idea/', IdeaViewName.as_view(), name='idea'),
    ### other views
]
```

This way your views will be in separate files and you will have routing to them

You should read official docs on django [routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/) because it will answer your questions in greater detail.

Comment: Hi there! I do understand what you intend to do here! This is for when urls is a single urls.py file, right? But what if the urls.py file is now split into a 'urls' folder with 'home.py', 'idea.py', 'business_partner.py', etc. in it that points to different urls? I couldn't find an answer within the docs regarding this, hence why I am here! The reason for splitting it this way is so that my views are segmented and easy to maintain :) Do correct me if I am going in the wrong direction!!

Comment: I updated the answer to be closer to what you want

Comment: i'm sorry your answer still does not have a nested directory. my question is related to de-structuring urls into a nested directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a django project with `django-admin startproject myproject`and a app with `django-admin startapp myapp` the default django project layout is like:

```
-basedir/
--myproject
---asgi.py
---__init__.py
---__pycache_/
---settings.py
---urls.py
---wsgi.py
--myapp
---migrations/
---admin.py
---apps.py
---__init__.py
---models.py
---tests.py
---views.py
---manage.py
```

Base project directory and also every django app comes with urls.py file.There is a couple benefits for this structure but mainly keeps all related urls in it's own appdir to keep maintenance easier. Than you can include your apps urls in `myproject/urls.py`. For example :

in myproject/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

But if you would like to change the layout of a django project you can try

```
basedir/
--root_configuration/
--root_apps/
```

to keep your project files in one file and all the django apps in one file